# fstream include in the header, but doesn't work?

Tags: c++, linux, ros, fstream

I edit the code to clarify the actual code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>

std::ofstream runtimeFile("cmg_operations_runtime.txt" , std::ios::out);

  

 void callhandler(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
{
   runtimeFile.open();
if (!runtimeFile)
        {
            std::cout << "cmg_operations_runtime.txt could not be opened.";
        }
         runtimeFile << "tempVector[j]" << ";\t";
         runtimeFile.close ();

        std::cout << "Runtime data stored." << std::endl;
 
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "main");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber Listener = nh.subscribe<nav_msgs::Odometry>("/odom", 100, callhandler);
  
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

error: `‘runtimeFile’ does not name a type
9 | runtimeFile.open ("cmg_operations_runtime.txt")

The error is the same, I hope someone to help me in this issue?`

Comment: Please don't spam tags.

Comment: There is a list of good C++ books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Look in the "Beginner" section.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ all code must be inside a function. Additionally all C++ programs must have a function called `main`.

Further your code opens the file twice, once when you declare the `runtimeFile` variable and once when you call `open`. Did you not think it strange that you have the file name twice in your code?  Don't open files twice. Finally, although it's not an error, there is no need to close the file, that will happen automatically.

Put all that together and you have a legal C++ program.

```
#include <fstream> 

int main()
{
    std::fstream runtimeFile("cmg_operations_runtime.txt" , std::ios::out);
    runtimeFile << "tempVector[j]" << ";\t";
}
```

**EDIT**

Some real code has been posted. Based on that I would remove the global `runtimeFile` variable and make it local to `callHandler` like the following

```
void callhandler(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::ofstream runtimeFile("cmg_operations_runtime.txt" , std::ios::out);
    if (!runtimeFile)
    {
        std::cout << "cmg_operations_runtime.txt could not be opened.";
    }
    runtimeFile << "tempVector[j]" << ";\t";
    std::cout << "Runtime data stored." << std::endl;
}
```

However I can't really see how the latest posted code causes the error described.

Comment: better use `std::ofstream` when the stream is used for writing only

Comment: Thank @john for ur response, I rewrite the actual code as u can see above, please can u help me why this error occur?

Comment: @بسمةاحمد See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @john the posted problem has been sloved but another error occured:syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 14: ` void callhandler(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)

Comment: @بسمةاحمد Well if you want to include the latest code and error I'll do my best to suggest a fix.

Comment: @بسمةاحمد There's something strange happening. Basically as soon as the header files are finished but the code starts you get an error. I don't know what might be causing that.

Comment: @بسمةاحمد It seems like one of your header files has a bug in it. But that seems quite unlikely. I think this is not a C++ problem, but something wrong in your environment or your tools. I'm afraid I can't really help you with that.

Comment: @john, hi the problem has been sloved I was running the code as: rosrun pkg_name node.cpp which is wrong the correct way to run is: rosrun pkg_name node